# Is there a good way to deal with form submission in Scalatra

Tags: scala, scalatra

Right now I'm just using `params` function to get the data that has been posted to an URL.

Is there any other way to deal with forms in Scalatra like in Play Framework? Does Scalatra support an object that can both be used to create a form and fill the form automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scalatra doesn't provide such a complex feature. It's not *complex* in the sense that it's *difficult to implement*, its complexity derives from the number of parties playing together.

First of all, you'd need a `Model` to represent objects in your domain, and Scalatra doesn't provide any model library by default. This model is then used by the runtime to convert arbitrary strings set in the HTTP request to an instance of some model. For example

- if the request is a `GET` and specifies a parameter like `user.id`, the binding software converts this string to an object of type `User`, found in the database by its ID.
- if the request is a `POST`, specifies three parameters like `user.name`, `user.password` and `user.birthday` and does **not** specify a `user.id`, the runtime builds an object of type `User` that is ready to be put in the DB with a simple `User.save()` - provided if passed the validation, if any, specified in the `User` class
- if the request is a `PUT` (or equivalent as explained in the Scalatra docs) and contains `user.id` and `user.birthday`, first an `User` is retrieved by ID, then its birthday is updated and finally is made available to your controller, ready to call `User.save()`

As you can see, this requires a model library, a binding library, and glue support in the runtime.

To generate the HTML form, you need a helper library that can inspect a model and output the HTML bits for you. For example, your library inspects the `User` class, detects that it has three public fields `name`, `password` and `birthday`, and, according to the convention of using `<model>.<property>` as the inputs' names, outputs

```xml
<form action="$$$$" method="$$$$">
  <input name="user.name" />
  <input name="user.password" />
  <input name="user.birthday" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note that

- the URL and the method can only be filled after some context is learned (for example routes)
- the same naming convention must be used by the binding library to deserialize a `User` object submitted by this form
- etc.

Once you have all the pieces put together, you have made up an MVC framework, so what's the point in using a tiny, RESTful software like Scalatra?